# Substitute variable with case-insensitive pattern matching and match shown in report title

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm creating a SQL*Plus script, where the user is being asked to provide the value for a substitute variable. In my query block I have:

```
select ...
from ...
where table1.column1 = '&substitute_variable';
```

Everything works just fine as long as user knows exacly how the value has been stored for `table1.column1`. If it has value *Oracle* and user inserts into prompt *Oracle*, the script ends successfully.

Now I want that any fragment from user input would match. E.g. if user provides *Ora*, then the output will be *Oracle...* etc.

How can I combine the

```
where table1.column1 = '&substitute_variable'
```

and

```
where table1.column1 like '%'
```

and including case insensitivity?

My script is:

```
accept subtitute_value prompt 'insert smt: '; 
some formating.. 
column ... format ... new_value something noprint 
ttitle center "Report for: " subtitute_variable skip 5 
break on something 
  select-statements
```

I can get the case-insensitive match using Aleksej's comment, with the

```
upper(table1.column1) like upper('%&substitute_variable%')
```

But it only shows the user-supplied fragment in the report title (from `ttitle`), not the actual value from the table that it matches. How can I get the actual column value into the report title?

Comment: `upper(table1.column1) like upper('%&substitute_variable%')`

Comment: Thank! Works. But now the ttitle:
`ttitle center "something: " subtitute_variable skip 5` 
displays only the fragment. How can i make it to display the actual value from table on the report?

Comment: i have:

accept subtitute_value prompt 'insert smt: ';
some formating..
column ... format ... new_value something noprint
ttitle center "Report for: " subtitute_variable skip 5 
break on something
With the upper(table1.column1) like upper('%&substitute_variable%'), it shows only inserted fragment in ttitle not the actual value from the table, that it matches.

Comment: If you have multiple matches in your table, which one would the ttitle show? Or do you want a new page for each new value from the table? Not sure that really makes sense, unless you (maybe) have a lot of duplication.

Comment: I don't know how IRL situation the duplicate (values that have the same starting fragment e.g.) problem should be solved but for my school work it's just important, that the ttitle in report states the value from the table that the user inserted fragment matches.

Comment: The `ttitle` would have to be reset for each value of the matches in your table -- which it can't do in one query. @AlexPoole has your best solution. I don't think you can get what you want from a simple sqlplus driven report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `ttitle` using a column value, [as shown in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref791):

> You can reference a column value in a top title by storing the desired value in a variable and referencing the variable in a TTITLE command

Using Aleksej's data but expanded to multiple rows, you can do:

```
set verify off

accept subtitute_value prompt 'insert smt: ';

ttitle center "Report for: " subttitle skip 5
column column1 new_value subttitle
break on column1 skip page

select column1, column2, column3
from table1
where upper(table1.column1) like upper('%&subtitute_value%')
order by column1; -- and others
```

Which gets:

```
insert smt: ora

                           Report for: 123 ORAC LE 333




COLUMN1                 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
-------------------- ---------- --------------------
123 ORAC LE 333              95 Some text
                             99 Some text

                             Report for: xxOracleyy




COLUMN1                 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
-------------------- ---------- --------------------
xxOracleyy                   13 Some text
                              7 Some text
                             42 Some text
                              5 Some text
                             71 Some text

7 rows selected.
```

The `column ... new_value subttitle` defines the `subtitle` referred to in the `ttitle` directive. Not that is not referred to as a substitution variable, to no `&` here. You need to break on the column being used for the title, as noted in the documentation. And if you *only* want to see the value in the title, not in the report itself, you can add `noprint` to that `column` directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> set verify off
SQL> accept subtitute_value prompt 'insert smt: ';
insert smt: ora
SQL> ttitle center "Report for: " &subtitute_value skip 5
SQL> select column1
  2  from table1
  3  where upper(table1.column1) like upper('%& subtitute_value%');

                                 Report for: ora




COLUMN1
----------------
xxOracleyy
123 ORAC LE 333
```

Comment: yes, the ttitle report for: ora should be Oracle instead

Comment: In my example I have 2 rows matching, so why should it be "Oracle" and not "ORAC LE", given that they both match?

Comment: Yes, if there are more then one matching the fragment, but if there's only one, then the full value from the table should be displayed int the ttitle.